# Wordpress. Making article items bigger

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am new to WP don't know how does the theme customization work. I've chosen receptar theme ([link](https://wordpress.org/themes/receptar/))

I want to make the article items on the main page bigger by default, as I would do with Ctrl +. How Can I do it?

I want to change it from this :
[image]
to this:
[image]

Comment: Do inspect element then find the class name for that item and after you did that edit it in your css file by for example changing the font-size

Comment: can you provide your website link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word of caution: always try to fix things yourself and let us know what you've tried before asking on SO. Everyone here is happy to help once you hit a roadblock.

Now, to fix the issue you need to modify the Width of the element. I changed it from 50% to 100%. When it is 50% it allows two items to be next to each other, so if it is 100% every item will take all the space it can, getting to what you're looking for.

You can copy and paste this code into your theme CSS styler:

```
.posts .hentry {
width: 100%;
}
```

Usually, all themes come with this, or if your version of Wordpress is 4.7+ you can do this through the customizer.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with CSS,
please go to your theme main style.css and add this CSS

```
.post {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This is a option but it's not the best. Imho the best solution is to get the declaration which have the `width: 50%` and overwrite this.

Comment: No problem the user already marks on right answers, thanks for suggestion